# flexbox with space-between, equal heigth, vertical and horizontal centered items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to build a menu with flexbox with the following ideas:
Space between the items, equal height, centered text (horizontal and vertical).

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

li {
  width: 32.25%;
  align-items: center;
}

span {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Item</span></li>
  <li><span>Item</span></li>
  <li><span>Item - much much much much much much much much much much more longer</span></li>
</ul>
```

What should I do to get a correct menu? What should I do to center the text horizontally and vertically?

[image: menu with flexbox]

Comment: How should be your desire output should look like?

Comment: In the meantime I added a picture of the menu I want to have.

Answer (score 2):

Make the `li` flex-parents also. No need for set heights. The `li` will all be the same height (of the tallest) and with `display:flex` you can align the content of the `li` as required.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 32.5%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

span {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Item</span></li>
  <li><span>Item</span></li>
  <li><span>Item - much much much much much much much much much much more longer</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `align-items: center;` to the `ul`.

> The CSS **align-items** property defines how the browser distributes space between and around flex items along the cross-axis of their container. This means it works like justify-content but in the perpendicular direction.

For more info, follow [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)

Refer code:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  width: 32.25%;
  align-items: center;
}

span {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Item</span></li>
  <li><span>Item</span></li>
  <li><span>Item - much much much much much much much much much much more longer</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks very much - I tried this but I couldn't get a menu with buttons to click. In the meantime I added a picture to my question - maybe it helps to find a solution.